# How many seconds count until bomb detonates in Counter Strike?

Tags: counter-strike

In Counter-Strike, is there any count (in seconds/minutes) until the bomb explode when it's first set-up? And can the timing be modified?

Comment: 45 in matchmaking, 35 in professional/league games.

Comment: In regards to edits, looks like this is being disputed, please see http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7580/should-a-question-be-modified-to-include-multiple-subjects

Comment: @Resorath BTW, the reverts by you and fbueckert trying to restore the question to being about 1.6 have only been reverting the tags, not the actual question. Also, the answer was similarly edited; not sure if that was intentional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most iterations of Counter-Strike by default it is set to 45 seconds. 
In most competitive and league matches, this value is changed to 35 seconds. **Note:** that since the Winter update 2015, the bomb timer has been modified to **40** seconds for both Competitive and most league matches.

This can be changed in the console by the server admin with the command:

```
mp_c4time "[time in seconds]"
```

in CS:Source and CS:GO the command is:

```
mp_c4timer "[time in seconds]"
```

Make sure to wrap time in quotes.

Answer (score 2):

From the [wiki](http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/C4):

> In the CS, CS:CZ and CS:S incarnations, the timer is set for 45 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

The time until the bomb im Condition Zero explodes is a server configuration setting by the name **mp_c4timer**, followed by an integer giving the seconds. According to the [Counter-Strike wikia](http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/C4) the default server setting is **mp_c4timer 45**, i.e. 45 seconds.

However, for example the [ESL Counter-Strike: Condition Zero 5on5 league](http://www.esl.eu/de/cscz/5on5/opening_cup/leagueinfo/) rules specify that

> mp_c4timer 35

i.e. 35 seconds is to be used.