# How long does it take the bomb to explode?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

After the Terrorist team in *Counter-Strike: Global Offensive* plants the bomb, the Counter-Terrorist team has to defuse it before it blows up.

After the bomb is planted at a bomb site, how many seconds does it take for the bomb to blow up?

Comment: If further discussion about this question is required, please take it to [Arqade Meta.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: [Link to said meta discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7580/4797)

Comment: Sorry to flag that question half a year since then, but it's been answered here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120218/how-many-seconds-count-until-bomb-detonates-in-counter-strike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default is 45 seconds. However, [this value is configurable](http://wiki.multiplay.co.uk/CS:GO/Command_list) and so it can be different( valid values are between 10 and 90 seconds inclusively) depending on which server you play on.

The standard for competitive play is usually 35 seconds.

Comment: By competitive play, do you mean competitive matchmaking, or professional leagues?

Comment: @avestar101 professional leagues for sure. Not sure about competitive matchmaking, I do not usually play that format.

Comment: In competitive matchmaking 45 seconds is the default. I'm not so sure if you can change it in matchmaking.

Comment: @Neffer_23 references to 'competitive' in my answer is not for the in-game 'competitive match making' but for other organized team play like ESEA.