# How many seconds until the bomb detonates in the Counter Strike: Source?

Tags: counter-strike-source

After I plant the bomb, how long do the Counter-Terrorists have before it explodes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many seconds count until bomb detonates in the Counter Strike series?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120218/how-many-seconds-count-until-bomb-detonates-in-the-counter-strike-series)

Comment: Anyone who thinks these should be separate questions probably shouldn't have an issue with the fact that @Decency has indeed created separate questions. He's doing exactly what we stated we thought was the proper method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a Fixed value, But the default value is 45 Seconds.
However, It's difference between servers. The timer can be set using:

> mp_c4timer "TimeInSeconds"

e.g.  `mp_c4timer "15"`. Now the bomb detonates is 15 seconds.